# How can I get the value of a int in a MongoDB collection (Python)

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that looks like this:

```
_id: 603fee86adf1b129a899a2d3
mail: "mateo"
amount: 1287
```

How can I get the value of `amount` using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest version goes like this using pymongo. You can get your connection details from Atlas and just need to put in username:password.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

cluster = MongoClient("your connection/login details")
db = cluster["your cluster name"]
collection = db["your collection name"]

for x in collection.find({}):
    mail, amt = x['mail'], x['amount']
    print("Mail %s has amount %s" % (mail, amt))
```

Comment: Bet you a nickel that that won’t work, @Kyle-Hurst .

Comment: Thanks that worked